# Need clarification on ANT and MAVEN

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ant

I was asked this question in an interview
**Can Ant and Maven be in same project?**

Can someone help me with this question??.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Don't work there.

Comment: @thekbb 

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Maven can call (mostly used for legacy reasons) ANT Task via the maven ANTRun Plugin and vice versa ANT Task may call maven via simple exec-Task.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning the Maven Ant tasks, although they've been retired a few years ago: http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html